# Part of this comment unreasonable?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Apparently, [my question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130410/is-this-user-storage-database-system-efficient) is bad. I got this comment explaining why:

> @Mirabilis Please edit your question to clarify it and respond to the comments you have received so far. The question is tagged database-design, so it seems reasonable to expect answers suggesting changes to the design. If that is out of scope, please say so. Including the definition (create table) statement might be useful if you do want that examined. Once improved, the question can be reopened.

Now that all seems reasonable and everything, except for:

> ...respond to the comments you have received so far...

What? I have been responding to every comment, until, well I had to go to sleep.

I'm new and everything (to this network) so it's understandable that my first question could not be of the best quality. It's also understandable that someone is doing something about it, and notifying me. But what isn't reasonable is to acuse them of not responding to comments, when you haven't given them at least, say, ten hours to wake up (if they are asleep).

Comment: You're overreacting. Chill

Comment: now you have to wait for the community to decide if it's a satisfactorily-answerable question. the moderator did you a HUGE favor by even pointing you in the correct direction

Comment: @Phil, I probably am :D.

Comment: @swasheck, oh really? Okay.

Comment: First of all, welcome to DBA.SE. On the other hand, I'm quite sure Paul White has the best intentions, and I can assume he didn't mean that you should respond immediately, but, very likely, that answering the comments would help you to get closer to a more clear definition of your problem and, therefore, increase the possibilities of re-opening the question. This, naturally, might attract well-contextualized and precise answers.

Comment: Exactly. That is how this site has more common with a forum than with a chat: no-one expects you to respond in real time. Your question has reached a certain state (put on hold), you have been notified of what you can do about that, you do what you can *when* you can, your question enters the reopen queue, the community re-evaluates and, hopefully, reopens it, to everybody's satisfaction.

Comment: @AndriyM, and they live happily ever after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please edit your question to clarify it and respond to the comments

I simply meant that *your responses to comments should also be edited into the question body*, as part of your improvements. It helps to have all the information in one place. No one wants to read a long chain of comments just to understand the question.

I did not intend to suggest that you had been ignoring comments at all.

My apologies for the delay in replying; I was asleep :)

I have edited your question for you now to include the comment updates, and reopened the question to answers.

Comment: That's okay apology accepted, and take my apology to for misunderstanding. And haha ;).

Comment: Oh and thanks for editing it. I probably should have done that myself. Anyway, thanks for being so patient :).